# Orchard Multi-Tenancy gives 500 error

Tags: iis, orchardcms, multi-tenant

I have and site made in Orchard CMS.  On transferring it to a new server, I get an error on any Multi-tenancy site.

When using Internet Explorer, I get a 500 server error.  When using Chrome on the PC I moved it over on, it loads without error.  On any other computer, I get errors only on the multi-tenancy sites I create (the core site works fine).

### Anyone have an idea as to what may be causing it?

I added the following to web.Config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

However, this isn't giving me expanded details when i connect.

Comment: What OS and IIS version? Have you turned on detailed errors in ASP.NET? What do you see?

Comment: I'm unable to connect to the server right now.  I will update when I can.  That server runs....windows server enterprise 2008 without  Hyper-V and i think it's using iis 7.

Comment: Ok...2008 or 2008R2?  Open Control Panel -> System....that will tell you.

Comment: Check app_data\logs for a detailed stack trace.

Comment: Tried to connect again today.  Checked file `orchard-error-2014.05.14.log` in app_data\logs and it's empty.

Comment: Can you check the following path in your server?
C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles and open up the latest file, and search for 500. It will have a few more details I presume. Post it here so that we can have a look.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I've checked all the files (ordering folders by date and checking) but can't see any 500 errors reported.  I've since gotten the server owner to set up a new server, and installed orchard separately.  The configuration is working perfectly.

Comment: I commented out this line in orchard's root web.config `<!-- Prevent IIS 7.0 from returning a custom 404/500 error page of its own. --> <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />` to give more details on 500 errors.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes got an error when I forgot to modify the URL of the site in the Settings.txt. I do not exactly remember if it was 500 or not. But you should check your settings.txt in case you published it to the new server and in case the URL has been changed. This can happen easily if you have a production and a testing URL.